# Регулярное выражение - найти путь SRC изображения с обязательным началом с http://

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как правильно отредактировать следующее регулярное выражение, чтобы искало пути SRC картинок с обязательным началом с http://?

```
/src="[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"/i
```

По идее, нужно добавить `^[http:\/\/]` в начале после `"`, но это некорректно сработало.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Квадратные скобки не нужны, просто так:

```
/src="http:\/\/[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"/i
```

Хотя, возможно, лучше даже так:

```
/src="https?:\/\/[^"]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)"/i
```